# How to convert a DateTime object into a String to put it into a database column?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I am very new in **C#** (I came from Java) and I have the following problem inserting a **DateTime** object field into a database:

I am creating and **UPDATE** query in the following way:

```
    public void update(DataModel.Vulnerability.VulnSmall v)
    {
        string whereCond = "";
        string strSQLParametri = "";
        _strSQL = "";               // The final query that will be execute

        System.Data.Common.DbCommand command;
        command = _connection.CreateCommand();

        // Update the record related to the Id field of the passed VulnSmall object:
        if (v.Id != null)
        {
            // Update the VulnerabilityAlertDocument table
            _strSQL = "UPDATE VulnerabilityAlertDocument ";    
            whereCond = "WHERE Id = @ID ";          // Selecting the record by the Id column value
            addParameter(command, "@ID ", v.Id);
        }

        // Update VulnerabilityAlertId field of the selected record:
        if (v.VulnerabilityAlertId != null)
        {
            _strSQL += "SET VulnerabilityAlertId = @VULNERABILITYALLERTID ,";
            addParameter(command, "@VULNERABILITYALLERTID", v.VulnerabilityAlertId);
        }

        .....................................
        .....................................
        .....................................

      // Update Published field of the selected record:
      if (v.Published != null)
      {
          _strSQL += "Published = @PUBLISHED ,";
          addParameter(command, "@PUBLISHED", v.Published);
      }
        .....................................
        .....................................
        .....................................

        // Update Language field of the selected record:
        if (v.Language != null)
        {
            _strSQL += "Language = @LANGUAGE ";
            addParameter(command, "@LANGUAGE", v.Language);
        }


        _strSQL += whereCond;

        command.CommandText = _strSQL;
        _executeNoQuery(command);


    }
```

The query work fine (update correctly the specified row in the table) until I don't try to set the new value of he **Published** column (that on my **Microsof SQL Server** have **datetime** as data type)

The problem is that the **v.Published** value is a **System.DateTime** object and when I do:

```
        if (v.Published != null)
        {
            _strSQL += "Published = @PUBLISHED ,";
            addParameter(command, "@PUBLISHED", v.Published);
        }
```

it go into error. I think that it could depend by the fact that I am putting a **DateTime** object into the _strSQL String.

What can I do to solve this problem? Have I to convert the **v.Published** value into a String in some way before put it into my **_strSQL** String? What am I missing?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Your Table datatype is date type and you want to put a string value into it ?  is that the question?

Comment: a. Can you show the code for your (I assume) addParameter method?
b. Could you kindly share the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `DateTime` value in the `DbCommand` object by wrapping it into `SqlParameter` object like below:

```
if (v.Published != null)
{
    _strSQL += "Published = @PUBLISHED ,";
    SqlParameter published = new SqlParameter("@PUBLISHED", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    published.Value = v.Published;
    addParameter(command, published); // you have to create an overload of `addParameter()` taking 2 arguments : `DbCommand` and `SqlParameter`
}
```

Overloaded `addParameter()`:

```
private void addParameter(DbCommand dbCommand, object value)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The .net `DateTime` structure offers a number of ways to output the DateTime object as a string, for example the `ToLongDateString()` or `ToShortDateString()` methods can be used to return a string with default formatting, or use any of the ToString(...) methods that accepts an argument to define the output format.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Or maybe you want to think about storing the DateTime as a DateTime type (if the SQL database you're using supports such a type) or as an integer type.